# How did Ancient Egyptians see Europe and how did they call the area?

Tags: europe, ancient-egypt

I was wondering how the Egyptians during the time of the Middle Kingdom saw Europe, besides Greece, Rome, and Macedonia? Did they ever travel to trade in or explore the northern part of the continent, or did they have a concept of it?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Welcome to H:SE. Interesting question. Three problems: 1. Ancient Egyptians had no concept of Europe (or of continents for that matter). 2. They did not compile comprehensive works on the geography of the world. 3. We have very, very few surviving sources (the Middle Kingdom you are talking about was 4000 years ago). That said, their designation for Greece (the Mycecaean civilization) was _probably_ TNJ (pronounced Tanaju or Tanaja or perhaps Danaya). See [footnote 4 here](https://ora.ox.ac.uk/objects/uuid:3f94654f-e34c-4a44-90ce-0ab45005b264).